# how to get value from an api javascript and display it in an input field as value

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display a variable from javascript api and display it on an input field as default value but I cant figure how

this is what I have currently forjavascript:

```
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/vcl/retrieve/"+url, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
        }).then((res) => res.json()).then((response) => {  
          console.log (response);
          const merchant_name = response[0].merchant_name;
          console.log(merchant_name);

        })
```

I want to diplay the merchant_name as a value on the html input field like below:

```
<input type="text" id="mobileNumber" class="input" value="merchant_name" required>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("mobileNumber").value = merchant_name`

Comment: That seems like a strange ID for the merchant name, BTW.

Comment: sorry the id was supposed to be merchantName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```html
<input type="text" id="mobileNumber" class="input" required>
```

and in JS:

```js
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/vcl/retrieve/"+url, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
        }).then((res) => res.json()).then((response) => {  
          console.log (response);
          const merchant_name = response[0].merchant_name;
          console.log(merchant_name);
          document.getElementById("mobileNumber").value = merchant_name;
        })
```

I hope that helps.